# Setup Table Relations

Tags: mysql

I'm having difficulties setting up relationships in my mysql database.  I have 2 tables. The relation for these tables is `company and sales_order_number`

I would have thought  mySQL workbench would have automatically detect this relationship but it hasn't.  I have found lots of references to using a foreign key to define a relationship but they are all based around a single field, my relationship is dependent on both the `company and sales_order_number` fields.

What is the correct way to define the relationships for these tables ? Do you have to use foreign keys to define relationships ?

Thanks.

```
Table: sales_order_header

 - (PK) sys_rowid

 - (UNIQUE) company 

 - (UNIQUE) sales_order_number 

 - Order Total
```

```
Table: sales_order_detail

 - (PK) sys_rowid

 - (UNIQUE) company

 - (UNIQUE) (FK) sales_order_number

 - (UNIQUE) sales_order_line

 - sales_order_line_total
```

Comment: 'Do you have to use foreign keys to define relationships ?' absolutely not, foreign keys are about referential integrity not relationships.

Comment: Given that FKs are about referential integrity you should have 1 in sales_order_header on company referencing your company table, company should not exist in sales_order_detail (it's redundant) but you should have an FK on sales_order_number which references sales_order_header

Comment: Company has to exist is sales_order_detail, this is a multi-company database, so we can have 2 sales orders with the same sales_order number but different companies (company is not the person placing the order).  So if I setup a FK just on sales_order_number then the relationship will not be correct.  Thanks.

Comment: 'we can have 2 sales orders with the same sales_order number but different companies' - you mean you can have 2 sales_order_header?

Comment: Yes, the database is mutli-company so one database / system can operate 2 separate companies.  There is a small amount of shared information, but for the most part every table has a company code in it.  If you are logged into "Company A" then you only see the records from your company, likewise if you are logged into "Company B".  So you can have 2 sales_order_headers with the same sales_order_number but different company codes.